# How to create a rule for several fields at the same time using FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I need to validate the following situation in an Asp.net MVC project: If the fields ServicoEmail, ServicoWebsite, ServicoBlog, ServicoRedeSocial and ServicoMensagemInstantanea are all false, return an error message. I tried to do as below, but it is not working ... Does anyone know how to help me?

```
RuleFor(ps => new { ps.ServicoEmail, ps.ServicoWebsite, ps.ServicoBlog, ps.ServicoRedeSocial, ps.ServicoMensagemInstantanea })
    .Must(ps=> ps.ServicoEmail == false && ps.ServicoWebsite == false && ps.ServicoBlog == false && ps.ServicoRedeSocial == false && ps.ServicoMensagemInstantanea == false)
    .WithMessage("É necessário selecionar pelo menos um Tipo de Serviço.");
```

My Class:

```
public abstract class ServicoWebCommand : Command
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Descricao { get; protected set; }

    public string FormatoCampo { get; protected set; }

    public bool ServicoEmail { get; protected set; }

    public bool ServicoWebsite { get; protected set; }

    public bool ServicoBlog { get; protected set; }

    public bool ServicoRedeSocial { get; protected set; }

    public bool ServicoMensagemInstantanea { get; protected set; }

    public bool PadraoSistema { get; protected set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify each of them individually or you can specify a custom validator.

### Way 1 :

```
RuleFor(ps => ps).SetValidator(new ServicoValidator());
```

and then write Validator implementation:

```
public class ServicoValidator: AbstractValidator<ServicoWebCommand>
{
    public ServicoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(t => t).Custom(ValidateServico);
    }


    private void ValidateServico(ServicoWebCommand ps, CustomContext validationContext)
    {
        if(ps.ServicoEmail == false && 
           ps.ServicoWebsite == false && 
           ps.ServicoBlog == false && 
           ps.ServicoRedeSocial == false && 
           ps.ServicoMensagemInstantanea == false)
         {
           validationContext.AddFailure("É necessário selecionar pelo menos um Tipo de Serviço.");
         }
    }
}
```

### Way 2:

```
RuleFor(ps => ps).Must(ps => Validate(ps));
```

and write the method to validate like:

```
private bool Validate(ServicoWebCommand ps)
{
    if(ps.ServicoEmail == false && 
       ps.ServicoWebsite == false && 
       ps.ServicoBlog == false && 
       ps.ServicoRedeSocial == false && 
       ps.ServicoMensagemInstantanea == false) 
        return false;

    return true;
}
```